# Eigen3 C++ Matrix library: Matrix type aliasing through usage of block method on static-sized Matrix types

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I'm a bit new in this forum, so please forgive me in case doing sthg wrong.

I'm trying to use C++ matrix library Eigen3.3.4 (tag 5a0156e40febif I'm not mistaken).

I'm trying to do some template programming with it, and some of my calls aren't resolved by the compiler. I'm certainly doing something wrong, but as I do not see a clear answer, I'm raising a post.

I'm trying to use the block method overload of the Matrix template class(the one with two template params and two integer arguments). I'm using it in a templatized class trying to extract a block of an argument.

The ***.block(Z,T) doesn't resolve OKAY when using an aliased type (i.e. typedef'ed), whereas it works just fine using a concrete type temporary argument. I'm using an std::tuple for parameter packing in the same object.

The aim would be to get the following call:

```
std::get<3>(my_tuple).block<3,4>(0,1)
```

to be used as an argument in a function, method or constructor. Any workaround will be just fine.

I managed to reproduce the problem (at least I think so) in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

class MyTypeSource
{
public:
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> CFULL_matrix_format;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> SUB_format;
};

template<typename Source>
class MyTypeDest
{
public:
    typedef typename Source::CFULL_matrix_format CFULL_matrix_format;
    typedef typename Source::SUB_format SUB_format;

    typedef
        std::tuple<CFULL_matrix_format>
        SecondaryObject;

    MyTypeDest(const CFULL_matrix_format & in_data) :
        _local(in_data)
    {

    }

    // The problems appears to be there...
    void dispSUB() const
    {
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> copy_with_raw_type = std::get<0>(_local);

        CFULL_matrix_format copy_with_aliased_type     = std::get<0>(_local);

        // THIS DOESN'T COMPILE/FUNCTION !
        //        std::cout   << "========================================"
        //                    << std::endl
        //                    << Eigen::Matrix3d(std::get<0>(_local).block<3,3>(0, 0))
        //                    << std::endl
        //                    << "========================================"
        //                    << std::endl;

        // ALTHOUGH "CFULL_matrix_format copy_with_aliased_type" AND "Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> copy_with_raw_type" SHOULD BE THE SAME,
        // DESPITE THE FACT THAT TYPEID DISPLAYS THE SAME TYPE NAME FOR BOTH ELEMENTS (AND TYPES)
        //                                       ==================
        //
        // => THIS CALL DOESN'T COMPILE,
        //        std::cout   << "========================================"
        //                    << std::endl
        //                    << copy_with_aliased_type.block<3,3>(0, 0)
        //                    << std::endl
        //                    << "========================================"
        //                    << std::endl;

        // => WHEREAS THIS ONE DOES, AND FUNCTIONS !
                std::cout   << "========================================"
                            << std::endl
                            << copy_with_raw_type.block<3,3>(0, 0)
                            << std::endl
                            << "========================================"
                            << std::endl;

        // THE SAME OCCURS WHEN TRYING TO USE THE BLOCK VALUE AS AN ARGUMENT INTO A METHOD/FUNCTION CALL
    }

    CFULL_matrix_format getFULL() const
    {
        return std::get<0>(_local);
    }

private:
    SecondaryObject _local;
};

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> my_matrix;
    my_matrix     <<    1.0,   2.0,   3.0,   4.0,   5.0,
                        5.0,   6.0,   8.0,  10.0,  12.0,
                       10.0,  12.0,  15.0,  20.0,  25.0,
                       12.0,  17.0,  22.0,  27.0,  32.0,
                       24.0,  37.0,  39.0,  14.0,   7.0;

    MyTypeDest<MyTypeSource> object(my_matrix);

    std::cout     << "========================================"
                  << std::endl
                  << object.getFULL()
                  << std::endl;

    std::cout     << "========================================"
                  << std::endl
                  << my_matrix.block<3, 3>(0, 0)
                  << std::endl;

    object.dispSUB();
}
```

Copiler is g++-4.8 under 64bits 14.04 in --std=c++11 mode; compiler error code is:

```
test_file.cpp: In member function ‘void MyTypeDest<Source>::dispSUB() const’:
test_file.cpp:51:29: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator<<’
                     << std::endl
                             ^
test_file.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void MyTypeDest<Source>::dispSUB() const [with Source = MyTypeSource]’:
test_file.cpp:96:20:   required from here
test_file.cpp:38:65: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
                     << Eigen::Matrix3d(std::get<0>(_local).block<3,3>(0, 0))
                                                             ^
test_file.cpp:50:21: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
                     << copy_with_aliased_type.block<3,3>(0, 0)
                     ^
```

and many more. I just focused on top three ones. Looks to me like it doesn't recognizes the block call.

I'm surely doing something stupid. I that case, just let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: Copiler is g++-4.8 under 64bits 14.04; compiler error code is:

Comment: Try to use `copy_with_aliased_type.template block<3,3>(0, 0)`. When you have a template inside a dependant name you need to explicitly tell the compiler that it is a template.

Comment: The comment by @super should solve your problem. See this for further information: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html

Comment: Problem SOLVED !

Comment: Sorry chtz, I've been using Eigen3 for less than 2 weeks. I guess it takes some time to know every use case...